# Issue with arrow box transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rptdou2y/)

The problem is that when I move the cursor to the space between the main menu and the sub menu,it vanishes (because the `.removeClass` is triggered), so is there any way to prevent that from happening ? I tried to make the `.arrowup` take the full width of the `.submenu` but I couldn't.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: You have `<span>` directly inside the `<ul>`, which is wrong.

Comment: @Paulie_D - Fiddle Edited.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Where should I put it ? When I put it outside the `<ul>` the problem is still there.

Comment: change your span into li and add a pseudo to increase height of ul>li so it doesn't loose the hover events once trying to reach submenu. http://jsfiddle.net/rptdou2y/7/ (typical beginner mistake ;) )

Comment: @GCyrillus That's awesome. Post it as an answer.

Comment: @GCyrillus Thanks a lot ! It's wonderful , post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: okay, so i turned my comment onto an answer, enjoy ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your span into li.

Add a pseudo to increase height of ul>li so it doesn't loose the hover events once trying to reach submenu.

http://jsfiddle.net/rptdou2y/7

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.headermain').hover(

    function () {
        $('.headersub').addClass("headermainopen");
    },

    function () {
        $('.headersub').removeClass("headermainopen");
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #b7b7b7;
}
/***Header**/
 #header {
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
}
#header>ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    -webkit-display: flex;
    -moz-display: flex;
    -o-display: flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background-color: #17243e;
    margin:10px auto;
    direction: rtl;
}
#header> ul>li {
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #17243e;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 8em;
    position: relative;
}
#header> ul>li:after {
    content:'';
    padding-bottom:20px;
    display:block;
}
#header> ul> li>a:hover {
    color:#17243e;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
#header> ul>li+li {
    border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
#header>ul>li> a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 70px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s ease;
    transition:background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s ease;
}
.headersub {
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 10em;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translateX(50%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: margin-top 0.3s, opacity 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: margin-top 0.3s, opacity 0.3s ease;
    transition: margin-top 0.3s, opacity 0.3s ease;
}
.headersub li a {
    color: #17243e;
    display: block;
    line-height: 2em;
}
.headersub .arrowup {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    right:50%;
}
.headermainopen {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.headermain .arrowup {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 10px solid white;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}
a:visited, a:link {
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
}
/***Header**/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#0">Text</a>
        </li>
        <li class="headermain"><a href="#0">Text</a>

            <ul class="headersub">
                <li class="arrowup"></li>
                <li><a href="#0">Text</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#0">Text</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```